# Are there PDEs where its solutions are sum of Fourier integral operators with phase functions are not homogeneous of order 1?

Tags: fourier-analysis, hyperbolic-pde

We know that the solution of hyperbolic partial differential equations is a sum of Fourier integral operators,
$$ Tf_{j}(x)=\int e^{i\phi(x,\xi,t)}a(x,\xi,t)f_{j}(\xi)d\xi $$
and We often consider In the Theory of FIO the phase function $ \phi $ homogeneous of degree 1 In the frequency variable $ \xi $. Is that mean the solution of all hyperbolic PDEs is given by sum of  Fourier integral operators with phases homogeneous of order 1? or there are cases where we can write solution with FIOs with non-homogeneous phases

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking here. Are you asking why the Fourier transform is defined the way it is? It would help if you wrote an explicit expression illustrating what you are talking about and what precisely you are asking.

Comment: @Michael Engelhardt i edited the question, i would like to know if we always can suppose phases homogeneous of order 1, or there are cases where phases are non-homogeneous.

Comment: There are two aspects here as far as I can see: On the one hand, can we always write the solution as a standard Fourier integral with homogeneous phase of order one? Of course we can, to the extent that we can apply such a transform at all. On the other hand, is such a form a useful ansatz that helps in practice to find a solution? It seems to me that is only the case if the exponential with homogeneous phase of order one happens to be an eigenfunction of the differential operator under consideration.

Comment: So, there is no sense to consider non-homogeneous phase function?

Comment: Well, if you find a differential operator of which the non-homogeneous phase function is an eigenfunction, then it would probably be useful. I can't think of an example off-hand - solution methods depend on the details of the operators, and it's not so clear how to answer a very generally phrased question such as yours.